# Apache: The requested URL / was not found on this server. Apache

Tags: php, windows, apache, url, http-status-code-404

I've installed Apache 2.2 server and PHP 5.3 on Windows XP SP3. After the initial install, Apache loaded the test page, i.e.,

**http:/localhost** (C:/Program Files/Apache2.2/htdocs/index.html) showed "It works!".

After configuring Apache and installing PHP, trying to load **http:/localhost/phptest.php** i.e. (C:/testsite/htdocs/phptest.php).

But this throws an error:

> Not Found. The requested URL /phptest.php was not found on this server.

I also get the same error now loading

```
http://localhost
```

**httpd.conf edits:**

```
ServerName localhost:80

DocumentRoot "C:/testsite/htdocs"

<Directory "C:/testsite/htdocs">
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
</Directory>

<IfModule dir_module>
    DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
</IfModule>

LoadModule php5_module "c:/testsite/php/php5apache2_2.dll"
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .php
PHPIniDir "C:/testsite/php"
```

File `php.ini` edits:

```
include_path = ".;C:\testsite\php\includes"
extension_dir = "C:/testsite/php/ext/"
```

System path:

The PHP directory was added to the Windows path, e.g.

```
PATH=C:\Windows\System32;C:\many_dir;C:\testsite\php
```

The only errors in the Apache error.log are:

> Warning: DocumentRoot [C:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.2   /docs/dummy-host.localhost] does not exist
>       Warning: DocumentRoot [C:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.2/docs/dummy-host2.localhost] does not exist
>       Warning: DocumentRoot [C:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.2/docs/dummy-host.localhost] does not exist
>       Warning: DocumentRoot [C:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.2/docs/dummy-host2.localhost] does not exist

The Apache service restarts successfully and is running. I can't find anything amiss. Can anyone spot any stupid errors?

Answer (score 5):

Try changing `Deny from all` to `Allow from all` in your conf and see if that helps.

Comment: Changed it to "Allow from all" and restarted Apache. Unfortunately still get the not found error.

Comment: It can be a problem with more than one .conf at "apache2/other" or some configuration of the same file

Answer (score 3):

In httpd.conf file you need to remove #

```
#LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

after removing # line will look like this:

```
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

And Apache restart

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but believe it or not is was a case of case sensitivity.

This on localhost:
http://localhost/.../getdata.php?id=3

Did not behave the same as this on the server:
http://server/.../getdata.php?id=3

Changing the server url to this (notice the capital D in getData) solved my issue.
http://localhost/.../getData.php?id=3

Answer (score 0):

## Non-trivial reasons:

- if your `.htaccess` is in DOS format, change it to UNIX format (in Notepad++, click `Edit>Convert` )
- if your `.htaccess` is in UTF8 **Without**-BOM, make it **WITH** BOM.

Answer (score 0):

#### One more additional reason I just ran into:

I've compiled PHP from the source code with apxs, so it did create an apache2 module with the php.load file (`/etc/apache2/mods-available/php.load`), but it didn't create the `php.conf` file with it, so it couldn't read the php files on the server, and I had to manually create it - also in the mods-available folder(next to the php.load file) and re-enable the module:

```
sudo a2dismod php
sudo a2enmod php
```

The module name is based on how you built your php, and what's the name of the .load file that was generated, so previously with 7.0, 7.2 and 7.4 it generated `php7.0.load`, `php7.2.load`, `php7.4load` files, in case of php 8.2 the file name was just `php.load`. The .conf file should match the name of the php.load version that you need to use.

This `php.conf` file contains the following:

```
# Using (?:pattern) instead of (pattern) is a small optimization that
# avoid capturing the matching pattern (as $1) which isn't used here
<FilesMatch ".+\.ph(?:ar|p|tml)$">
    SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
</FilesMatch>
<FilesMatch ".+\.phps$">
    SetHandler application/x-httpd-php-source
    # Deny access to raw php sources by default
    # To re-enable it's recommended to enable access to the files
    # only in specific virtual host or directory
    Require all denied
</FilesMatch>
# Deny access to files without filename (e.g. '.php')
<FilesMatch "^\.ph(?:ar|p|ps|tml)$">
    Require all denied
</FilesMatch>

# Running PHP scripts in user directories is disabled by default
#
# To re-enable PHP in user directories comment the following lines
# (from <IfModule ...> to </IfModule>.) Do NOT set it to On as it
# prevents .htaccess files from disabling it.
<IfModule mod_userdir.c>
    <Directory /home/*/public_html>
        php_admin_flag engine Off
    </Directory>
</IfModule>
```

Based on this I also theorize that if you are missing the apache2 php module - like, you didn't compile php from the source, but you also didn't install the apache module at all -, then you can get the same error.

In my case this happened when I built a new CI server and was executing the functional & unit tests with codeception.

Additionally, when I opened port for my IP, to be able to investigate the page with my browser, what I saw in the code inspector was that the `<?php` open and `<?` closing tags were just replaced with html comment `<!--` open and `-->` closing tags and the php code was just in-between them.

Comment: This actually happened a few times with me, but I just keep forgetting about it and then I spend a whole day each time to figure out what the issue is. So I thought that I write it down, so next time I'll find the answer easier.