# PHP MVC Framework Issue

Tags: php, model-view-controller

Learning the PHP MVC framework is entirely new to me. I've used ChatGPT to show me a basic PHP MVC folder & file structure.

I have a demo website that will use my own MVC framework that has a books gallery on the homepage. When the user clicks on a specific book from the list of books in a gallery on the homepage, the books details page will load only that specific book to show it's details.

Although ChatGPT seems to have gotten majority of the folder and file structure correct, it's still not properly loading the details page. I keep getting the following error after clicking on a specific book on the homepage:

"Not Found
The requested URL was not found on this server."

Here's how my folders are structured:

```
index.php
Models
    - Books.php
Views
    - home.php
    - details.php
controllers
    - BooksController.php
```

*index.php file*

```
<?php
header("Location: controllers/BooksController.php");
exit;
?>
```

*Books.php*

```
<?php

class Books {
    private $conn;

    public function __construct($conn) {
        $this->conn = $conn;
    }

    #homepage/default page function:
    public function getAllBooks() {
        $query = "SELECT * FROM book_details";
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($query);
        $stmt->execute();
        $result = $stmt->get_result();
        return $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    }

    #details page when user clicks on a specific book for details of book:
    public function getBookById($id) {
        $query = "SELECT * FROM book_details WHERE id = ?";
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($query);
        $stmt->bind_param("i", $id);
        $stmt->execute();
        $result = $stmt->get_result();
        return $result->fetch_assoc();
    }
}
?>
```

*home.php*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Home Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>List of Books</h1>
    <ul>
        <?php foreach ($books as $book) { ?>
            <li>
                <a href="details.php?action=details&id=<?php echo $book['id']; ?>">
                    <?php echo $book['name']; ?>
                </a>
            </li>
        <?php } ?>
    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

*BooksController.php*

```
<?php
require_once('../models/Books.php');
// Create a database connection
$conn = new mysqli("localhost", "username", "password", "booksdb");

if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$booksModel = new Books($conn);

if(isset($_GET['action']) && $_GET['action'] == 'details') {
    if(isset($_GET['id'])) {
        $book = $booksModel->getBookById($_GET['id']);
        include('../views/details.php');
    } else {
        // Handle if no ID is provided for details view
        echo "Invalid ID";
    }
} else {
    $books = $booksModel->getAllBooks();
    include('../views/home.php');
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

*details.php*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Book Details</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Book Details</h1>
    <?php if($Book) { ?>
        <h2><?php echo $Book['name']; ?></h2>
        <p>Description: <?php echo $Book['desc']; ?></p>
        <p>Category: <?php echo $Book['category']; ?></p>
    <?php } else { ?>
        <p>Book not found!</p>
    <?php } ?>
</body>
</html>
```

So, my questions are:

1. Is this even the proper basic structure of a php mvc framework as far as the folders and file structures go?
2. What exactly is wrong with the way that the index.php and details.php files are interacting? The details page never loads a specific book from the homepage. What exactly should be in the index.php file?

Any support is appreciated.

I tried the code above, expected the details page to load the details of a book from the homepage, but it did not properly load a details page.

Comment: **Don't use AI-models, like Chat-GPT for tutorials!** Since you had this Q originally tagged *codeigniter*, you could read this [tutorial](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/tutorial/index.html#overview), which quite nicely explains what MVC is and how you use the framework to build MVC applications. I'm sure for the other tag *Laravel*, you'll find a similar tutorial on their official website

Comment: @Vickel actually, the reason that I added those tags was for SEO so that those who know/understand Codeigniter and Laravel, are the same people who would know the answer to this question. Is there something in the posting rules that states we cannot use these tags while creating a post? BTW, I don't want to use any libraries or third-party tools to design a MVC. I'd like to learn it from scratch to create my own framework.

Comment: What is your document root? "*after clicking on a specific book on the homepage*" - what URL is the home page, what URL is the book you clicked on, and what URL did you end up on?

Comment: *Is there something in the posting rules that states we cannot use these tags while creating a post?*: you may use up to 5 tags to describe your Q. Using two different framework tags makes your Q much broader/needing focus, which is a reason to Close a Q. Sincerely I would edit out point 1. (which would most likely generate opinion-based answers) of your Q so it focuses only on current point 2.

Answer (score 0):

So there are a couple of things here with why your link isn't working.

Your error message looks like it is coming from Apache rather than from your php code.  Which you might be able to solve using this question: [Apache: The requested URL / was not found on this server. Apache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20696603/apache-the-requested-url-was-not-found-on-this-server-apache)

However, your controller is supposed to be doing the logic for what view to return to the user.  So you want to change the link for your books to `?action=details&id=<?php echo $book['id']; ?>` (get rid of `details.php`).  You do want to directly call this, you want to direct things through your controller and let it determine what to do.

Comment: I'll look over the Apache link in just a minute. So, what doesn't make sense to me is that you're saying to get rid of the "details.php" in the URL, but then there is no way to process the details without using this script? I tried getting rid of "details.php", but now nothing loads at all from the books gallery on the homepage. The homepage just reloads and doesn't load any books detail page.

Comment: Your controller is supposed to determine based on either the url or GET parameters which models to get and which view to display.  Your links should be directing through the controller and display the details view.  If the page just reloads, you aren't passing the GET parameters to the page.

Comment: So, based on the current files/code ChatGPT has created, could you show me a sample of what the way it should be? Thanks again.

Comment: what should go in the index.php file?

Comment: don't do the location change, just do an include on your controller